# Cannot add a constant coefficient to LineIntegrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, coefficients

I'm quite confused on how you're supposed to use constant coefficients in Mathematica integrals. The upvoted and accepted answer on Mathematics stackexchange (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48021/452937) seems to imply that it just works if the constant coefficient is not defined. However, I cannot get this behavior to work.

For example,

I have this line integral,

```
LineIntegrate[
 0.5 * Dot[{x, y}/ 
    Norm[{x, y}], ({x, y} - point)/(Norm[{x, y}]^2)], {x, 
   y} \[Element] Circle[]]
```

If I just want to take this integral and multiply it by some constant `a`, I would think I could just do this

```
LineIntegrate[
 0.5 * a*  
  Dot[{x, y}/ Norm[{x, y}], ({x, y} - point)/(Norm[{x, y}]^2)], {x, 
   y} \[Element] Circle[]]
```

And while it does work, it also outputs a bunch of errors.
[image]

Comment: I was looking at the documentation, and it looks like `LineIntegrate` is intended for only numeric calculations (including in terms of quantities like `E` and `Pi`) and not for symbolic calculations in terms of arbitrary variables. I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: If you replace 0.5 by an accurate number 1/2 it works.

Comment: @DanielHuber This does not work for me in version 14
`
LineIntegrate[
 a*(1/(2*Pi)) *  
  Dot[{x, y}/ Norm[{x, y}], ({x, y} - point)/(Norm[{x, y}]^2)], {x, 
   y} \[Element] Circle[]]
`

Comment: I checked again and it worked, it evaluates to Pi. I used several values for point. It even works if pint is not defined. I have windows 10.